# Unicode bidi text algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, bidi

Is there a C# version of the Unicode algorithm that takes a Unicode string and breaks it into runs that can be correctly rendered? Each run should be either left-to-right or right-to-left.

We understand this is part of the Java ICU4J, but that is a large library, and we're only looking for this specific functionality, to render text correctly.

Comment: It is built into Windows and used when rendering strings.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: No, should have added that we need this to be platform-independent. We're using C# on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the unicode standard for bidi handling:

[UNICODE BIDIRECTIONAL ALGORITHM](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/)

Also try: [this](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/bidi.jsp)

Implementations:

1. [JAVA](http://www.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/BidiReferenceJava/)
2. [C++](http://www.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/BidiReferenceCpp/)

I'm sure you will be able to convert them to c# fairly simply